# Does selenium-side-runner have a command-line option for running in "verbose mode"

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am running selenium-side-runner in a docker container.  I would like to be able to see the commands that have successfully executed, so far, so that I can identify which command is causing the error that I am trying to debug.  And of course, the test completes without any failures when run interactively in the IDE.

My question: does selenium-side-runner have an option for running it in "verbose" mode?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to ask this question on the seleniumhq slack channel and I got back the following reply, which I thought I should share here:

> Currently selenium-side-runner doesn't have an interactive mode, we'll
>   be changing that as well with the move to electron

So, I have given up on the idea of composing my tests with the IDE, for now.

I will be using webdriver calls.